# Difference between x[:] and x[...] in Numpy

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I am confused about the difference between `x[:]` and `x[...]` in Numpy.

For example, I have this 2-d array

```
[[4, 1, 9],
[5, 2, 0]]
```

When I tried to print out `x[:]` and `x[...]`, they both gave me the same output:

```
[[4, 1, 9],
  [5, 2, 0]]
```

However, when I tried to broadcast it by adding one dimension

```
print(np.broadcast_to(x[:,None],(2,3,3)))
print(np.broadcast_to(x[...,None],(2,3,3)))
```

They gave me different results.

```
[[[4 1 9]
  [4 1 9]
  [4 1 9]]

 [[5 2 0]
  [5 2 0]
  [5 2 0]]]


[[[4 4 4]
  [1 1 1]
  [9 9 9]]

 [[5 5 5]
  [2 2 2]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

I am trying to figure out the difference but cannot.

Comment: There's only a difference when you extend this use case to more dimensions, `...` expands as an indexing operation, so `x[..., 0]` returns the first element from the last axis, while `x[:, 0]` returns the first element from axis `1`, for example. It can also be used in the middle of indexing operations, and will insert the correct number of full slices, so for a 4D arrays, `x[0, ..., 0]` is equivalent to `x[0, :, :, 0]`

Comment: Correct me if I get your answer wrong.  `:` represents only one dimension, and `...` represents any amount of dimensions?

Comment: Trailing dimensions are added as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [91]: x = np.array([[4, 1, 9],
    ...: [5, 2, 0]])
In [92]: x
Out[92]: 
array([[4, 1, 9],
       [5, 2, 0]])
```

These just make a whole slice, a `view` of the original:

```
In [93]: x[:]
Out[93]: 
array([[4, 1, 9],
       [5, 2, 0]])
In [94]: x[...]
Out[94]: 
array([[4, 1, 9],
       [5, 2, 0]])
In [95]: x[:,:]
Out[95]: 
array([[4, 1, 9],
       [5, 2, 0]])
```

Trailing : are added as needed, but you can't supply more than the number of dimensions:

```
In [96]: x[:,:,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-96-9d8949edcb06>", line 1, in <module>
    x[:,:,:]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

`None` adds a dimension:

```
In [97]: x[:,None].shape       # after the first
Out[97]: (2, 1, 3)
In [98]: x[...,None].shape     # at the end
Out[98]: (2, 3, 1)
In [99]: x[:,:,None].shape     # after the 2nd
Out[99]: (2, 3, 1)
In [100]: x[:,None,:].shape    # same as 97
Out[100]: (2, 1, 3)
In [101]: x[None].shape        # same as [None,:,:] [None,...]
Out[101]: (1, 2, 3)
```

with a scalar index

```
In [102]: x[1,:]          # same as x[1], x[1,...]
Out[102]: array([5, 2, 0])
In [103]: x[...,1]        # same as x[:,1]
Out[103]: array([1, 2])
```